# Why when making a sphere child of a cube the sphere is losing his shape?

Tags: unity

When I drag to the scene a new sphere it looks like a ball a rounded ball.
When I drag the sphere to be a child in this case of a cube the sphere looks like ellipse.

[image: Sphere one is not child the light blue is child]

Is there any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the cube, or any parent of the cube, is scaled to (1,1,1). Otherwise, any children -- in your case the sphere -- will get scaled along with the parent and warped.

Comment: The reason the cube is not scaled to 1,1,1 because I wanted the cube to be like a hand and the sphere to be at the end of the hand.  Like the hand is holding the sphere.

Comment: That's fine, but that's the reason your sphere is warped is because of its parent scale. Instead you could have an empty gameobject parent for the cube and the sphere, scaled to (1,1,1), at the location you want the "hand" to be.